# Fetch all Nuget dependencies from .csproj file as DLLs to a specified directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, .net-core

Is there any way to fetch all Nuget dependencies from .csproj file as DLLs to a specified directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to fetch all Nuget dependencies from .csproj file as DLLs to a specified directory?

Do you want to fetch dll files to a specified directory based on `.csproj` file? If yes, NuGet doesn't support this, but you can use other technologies to meet this requirement, like Power Shell.

To accomplish this, create a Power Shell scripts `GetDllFiles.ps1` under the project file directory with following code:

```
$projectFiles = get-childitem . *.csproj -Recurse 

foreach( $projectFile in $projectFiles )
{
    $projectXml = [xml] (get-content $projectFile.FullName)
    $projectDir = $projectFile.DirectoryName

    Write-Host "# $($projectFile.FullName) #"


    foreach( $itemGroup in $projectXml.Project.ItemGroup )
    {
        if( $itemGroup.Reference.Count -eq 0 )
        {
            continue
        }

        foreach( $reference in $itemGroup.Reference )
        {
            if( $reference.Include -eq $null )
            {
                continue
            }

            if( $reference.HintPath -eq $null )
            {
                Write-Host ("{0}" -f $reference.Include)
            }
            else
            {
                $fullpath = $reference.HintPath
                if(-not [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted( $fullpath ) )
                {
                    $fullPath = (join-path $projectDir $fullpath)
                    $fullPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath("$fullPath")
                }
                Write-Host $fullPath
                Copy-Item $fullPath D:\Test
            }
        }
    }

    Write-Host ''
    Start-Sleep –s 10
}
```

This Power Shell scripts grabs every `.csproj` file under the current directory, and inspects each Reference. For assemblies referenced from the GAC, just the name is output. For assemblies outside the GAC, output the full path of the assemblies, then you can copy them to the specified directory.

**Update for Comment:**

> but I want a bit different thing - to fetch all NuGet packages from .csproj and "unpack" them into a specified directory in order to have all DLLs that my application depends on.

If you want to fetch entire nuget packages to the specified directory instead of just the dll files, you can use a simple nuget command line to achieve it:

```
nuget restore "xx.csproj" -OutputDirectory "SpecifiedDirectoryPath"
```

This command line will fetch entire nuget packages and unpack them into a specified directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I want a bit different thing - to fetch all NuGet packages from .csproj and "unpack" them into a specified directory in order to have all DLLs that my application depends on.

Comment: @AndrewOrlov, if you want to fetch all NuGet packages from .csproj and "unpack" them into a specified directory installed of just the dll files, you can use nuget restore command line achieve it, you can refer to my update for detail info. Hope this helps.