# Given a dotnet sdk csproj file, how to resolve Nuget dependency DLL files that will be used?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget

Given a .NET SDK .csproj File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows;net48</TargetFrameworks>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x64</Platform>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RunPostBuildEvent>OnOutputUpdated</RunPostBuildEvent>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

we are using [Central Package Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/central-package-management) for the NuGet dependencies, so all that is listed in the `PackageReference` is the ID of the package. (We used to have `packages.config` that listed id, version and `targetFramework`.)

Now, given this csproj file, I would like to find out which files exactly from the referenced NuGet Packages will be used and copied to the output folder, without actually having to build the project.

- Desired Input: `abc.csproj` (and possibly `x.sln`)
- Desired Output: List of (dll) files that come from the nuget packages (in the example above that would be the dlls of the 3 nuget packages listed as well as all transitive dependencies of these) but *not* the (dll) files that are built by the project itself or that are pulled in by `ProjectReference`s.

I have seen [Fetch all Nuget dependencies from .csproj file as DLLs to a specified directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47340779/fetch-all-nuget-dependencies-from-csproj-file-as-dlls-to-a-specified-directory) , but e.g. using `nuget restore` to unpack the nuget packages will just give me the nuget folders that contain *all* framework versions of the package:  E.g. in the case of `System.Memory` I get a `System.Memory.4.5.5` folder with a `lib` subfolder for all platforms.

How would I **then** find out *which* of the files / framework versions of these nuget packages are used?

I'm currently looking into the [Microsoft.Build](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build) lib but haven't found anything useful yet.

So how would one go about getting at this info?

Comment: When NuGet restores, it writes a file `obj\project.assets.json` with all the selected assets. This is what the .NET SDK reads to figure out how to do the build.